# Python shows wrong version in command prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, python

I have downgraded my version of Python from 2.7.9 to 2.7.4 for compatibility with a legacy piece of software. On Windows 7 x64 computer. I removed Python 2.7.9 and then installed 2.7.4 into the `C:\Python27` directory.

In command prompt

```
C:\Users\mem48>python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I have checked my path variable and it points to `C:\Python27`and even explicitly calling the `python.exe` give the same result

```
C:\Users\mem48>C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The `C:\Python27\README.txt` states that it is version 2.7.4, and I have combed my system to check that I don't have version 2.7.9 installed anywhere else.

I have also tried uninstalling python and reinstalling 2.7.4 with no effect.

What is causing the 2.7.9 version to run and where is it coming from?

Comment: You have manually deleted python.exe and replaced it from the 2.7.4 ?archive

Comment: No I unistalled it using Add/Remove Programs

Comment: in a command prompt, type `where python` and hit enter.  what does it say?

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe

Comment: I suggest you try my method.

Comment: @falcs well that confirms that you only have one python.exe in your path.  if you right click python.exe and go to properties and details, does it give a version?

Comment: @Keltari the python.exe properties doesn give a version but does say it was created on 6th April 2013

Comment: @Ramhound I've tried deleting the files and reinstalling with no effect

Comment: what's `import sys - 
print sys.path`
have to say?

Comment: ['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\python27\
\lib', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\python27
', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: Why is a .zip file in your System32 directory?  I can only conclude what your downloading isn't actually the version you believe it to be.  You deleted all those files yourself then extract the archive to the same file, correct?

Comment: I can't actually find the zip file in system32 there is a python27.dll The version I am installing if from https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.4/